# Is there an equivalent for ImageMagick’s “-shear” command in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

FWIW, I must run this on Windows platform.

I have a series of videos shot in identical conditions (mounted camera shooting trains), all exhibiting the same rolling shutter effect when train passes. Luckily, since the camera is fixed, the rolling shutter effect is identical between all videos.

Now, if I extract a frame, I can “fix” individual frames with ImageMagick's `-shear` parameter.

Here is a sample of what ImageMagick `-shear` command does to one frame:

> [image: Here is a sample of what ImageMagick -shear command does to one frame.]

Is it possible to to do it for the entire video using FFmpeg?

Comment: took literally 37 seconds to research "ffmpeg video filter shear" to determine that the answer is "yes, it is possible"

Comment: Any links? I spent an hour searching, GPTing. Could not find anything.

Comment: it's the [first result on google](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#shear) when you type in that phrase (this question is the second result by the way)

Comment: Darn, not sure how I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: @JaromandaX “I spent an hour searching, GPTing.” Please use this lesson/example to _not_ use ChatGPT so much.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Jaromanda X's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1824643/is-there-an-equivalent-for-imagemagics-shear-command-in-ffmpeg#comment2873713_1824643), this is the command I a looking for:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -vf "shear=-0.0:0.22" out_shear.mp4
```